# An adjustable/variable switch case in java

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement

I have a lot of methods that look like the following:

```
switch(myEnum) {
    case a :
    case b :
    case c :
    case d :
        modifier = 1.1;
        break;
    default :
        break;
}
```

It would be perfect if i had the opportunity to make every case and the modifier variable, so i can have one method with 6 parameters, 4 for the cases and 2 for the modifier. Something like the following (pseudo):

```
public void setModifier(case1, case2, case3, case4, modifier, value) {
    switch(myEnum) {
        case case1 :
        case case2 :
        case case3 :
        case case4 :
            modifier = value;
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

modifier and value shouldnt be a problem, but how do i solve the variable switch cases? Is this even possible in java with a switch-statement?

Comment: Why not use if rather than use switch?

Comment: `modifier` will only get impacted by the change inside the method. Show us the practical example because this one is quite unclear.

Comment: Do you want modifier the modifier variable in switch cases

Comment: What are you doing?

Comment: modifier should be one of a group of member of the class this is in, but i want to change only the one that is given as a parameter. Now as you mention it, there should be some kind of structure before the first break that checks the modifer and determines which modifier should be modificated. But this isnt what iam trying  to ask. Its more about the switch cases. Im going to simplify the question in a moment.

Comment: NOTE: I made a rollback to the old version, because Arne Burmeisters answer reffered to this and it solved my Problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this approach:

- You cannot change the value of a parameter passed so that the value is changed for the calling code (in Java, except for a holder kind type like `AtomicReference` etc).
- Trying to make code generic because of possible reuse is not always a good idea, this tends to create complex generic code instead of readable specific.
- It looks like your code is mostly an if, so why note write it in this way?

If I understand your snippet right, I would try the following inline approach:

```
if (EnumSet.of(a, b, c, d).contains(myEnum)) {
  modifier = 1.1;
}
```

This is from my perspective much cleaner and therefore has less need to extract it in a general way and very flexible (any number of enum values and any kind of action possible).

If you really need such an approach, a functional interface can do the job:

```
setModifier(myEnum, () -> modifier = 1.1, a, b, c, d);

public <E extends Enum<E>> void setModifier(E current, Runnable action, E... allowed) {
  Arrays.stream(allowed)
      .filter(one -> one == current)
      .findAny()
      .ifPresent(found -> action.run());
}
```

As you can see this creates a lot more code which is not necessary if not used spread around classes very often. The code above only works for `modifier` being a member not a local variable due to implicit final behavior.

Comment: Is this EnumSet the java.util class? I cant recreate this exact piece of code, but it looks promising.
EDIT: It works, thats exactly what i needed, super compact.